# How to repeat RxJS from() but skip first emission

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs7

I have the following code which I expect should emit for each member in the `scheduleEntries` array, and each `scheduleEntry` should repeat forever, and I'm trying to get the first emission of each array member to be skipped. How can I get it to work?

Right now it doesn't emit at all with `skip(1)`

```
import { Observable, from, mergeMap, of, repeat, skip, timer } from 'rxjs';

class Schedule {
  private scheduleEntries = [
    { value: true, countdown: 48395 },
    { value: true, countdown: 38395 },
    { value: false, countdown: 42394 },
    { value: true, countdown: 4835 },
  ];

  private lockEmitter$: Observable<ScheduleEntry>;

  constructor() {
    this.lockEmitter$ = from(this.scheduleEntries).pipe(
      skip(1), // skip the first emission for each entry
      mergeMap(entry => of(entry).pipe(
        repeat({ delay: () => this.delayedObservableFactory(entry) }),
      )),
    );
    this.lockEmitter$.subscribe(console.log);
  }

  private delayedObservableFactory(entry: ScheduleEntry) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      timer(entry.countdown).subscribe(() => observer.next({}));
    });
  }
}


interface ScheduleEntry {
  value: boolean;
  countdown: number;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified the observable produced by `delayedObservableFactory()` returns an observable that completes? It looks like it never does.

Comment: @JeffMercado I forgot one detail in the question: I want it to repeat forever. That's why it never completes.

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to move skip before pipe?

Actually looking again skip is applying the whole array but you may need to skip each entry as your code comment suggests (missed that detail first time round)

```
  mergeMap(entry => of(entry).pipe(
    delay(entry.countdown),
    skip(1),
    repeat()
  )),
```

Comment: Before which pipe? The first?

Comment: sorry I looked again and I think you need to skip(1) on each entry inside the array, have update my answer with a snippet

Answer (score 0):

When you use `from`, we require `concatMap` to ensure the items are executed in order, please find below stackblitz

```
import './style.css';

import { rx, map } from 'rxjs';
import {
  Observable,
  from,
  mergeMap,
  of,
  repeat,
  skip,
  timer,
  delay,
} from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

class Schedule {
  private scheduleEntries = [
    { value: true, countdown: 48395 },
    { value: true, countdown: 1000 },
    { value: false, countdown: 1000 },
    { value: true, countdown: 1000 },
  ];

  private lockEmitter$: Observable<ScheduleEntry>;

  constructor() {
    this.lockEmitter$ = from(this.scheduleEntries).pipe(
      skip(1),
      concatMap((item: ScheduleEntry) => of(item).pipe(delay(item.countdown))),
      repeat()
    );
    this.lockEmitter$.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}

new Schedule();

interface ScheduleEntry {
  value: boolean;
  countdown: number;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-afexks?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Reading what you're asking for, you mention you want to `skip` the first emission, but looking at your code, I think all you want is to actually `delay` all the emissions (including the first one).

Here's how it can be done:

```
from(scheduleEntries)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((entry) => 
      of(entry).pipe(
        delay(entry.countdown),
        repeat()
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

It's not so far from what you had, but there's a subtle difference in using a delay outside of the repeat, it means that even the first emission will be delayed (and then repeated indefinitely).

Here's a [live demo on Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ulb4bq?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code using the `interval` operator like this:

```
this.lockEmitter$ = from(this.scheduleEntries).pipe(
  mergeMap(entry => interval(entry.countdown).pipe(
    map(() => entry) // or use entry.value if you only interested in the boolean
  )),
);
```